# How can i view solutions of Solve as multiples of pi in mathematica 10

Tags: mathematica

i am new to Mathematica and can't find the option to show solutions of Equations like

```
Solve[6.5 == 2 \[Pi]*r]
```

as multiple of pi. I only get the numerical output

```
{r -> 1.03451}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe this question is more suited for [Mathematica.SE](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try filling in $13/2$ instead of $6.5$.

When using points, Mathematica will automatically treat everything numerically, and hence also gives rounded answers.

Comment: Since I am lazy, I use to write $6.5=65/10$, $6.543=6543/1000$ ! May I confess that I don't understand why they don't rationalize automatically numbers ?

Comment: @Claude Leibovici That's probably because mathematicians (the group demanding exact answers) usually use fractional notation, but people processing data from an experiment (think chemistry or physics), which is usually in decimal form, would rather want numerical answers.

Comment: I am part of the second group but I am very sensitive to the beauty of results given in closed form, whatever they are !